# Display Content Of Website One On Website Two

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've built a blog which contains multiple categories, which span multiple niches, and would like to split/group several categories over several url's.

So I have:

`website-one.com/blog/category.php?name=$1&page=$2`, which rewrites to `website-one.com/blog/music/1`.

So lets assume I have:

`website-one.com/blog/music/1`, `website-one.com/blog/fashion/1` and `website-one.com/blog/sport/1`.

I want to be able to use the same website but to mirror the content on a completely sepperate domain:

`website-two.com/blog/cooking/1`.

So I'm not looking to completely copy one site on another, but select the categories I'd like to display on each domain, using website one as the main administrative site.

Is it possible to achieve this with a simple rewrite rule or server side scripting?

My concern comes with the pagination, meaning that when people click on the `Next Page` button they are not redirected back from domain two to domain one (`website-two.com/blog/cooking/1` to `website-one.com/blog/cooking/2`).

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess on website-one.com add cooking/1 rewrite to second domain

`RewriteRule ^blog\/cooking\/1$ http://website-two.com/blog/cooking/1 [R=301,L]`

In .htaccess on website-two.com add cooking/2 rewrite back to first domain

`RewriteRule ^blog\/cooking\/2$ http://website-one.com/blog/cooking/2 [R=301,L]`